# Can you change the linter in grunt.js to jslint?

Tags: javascript, jslint, gruntjs

I see that the default linter in grunt.js is jshint, but I've gotten used to using jslint. Is it possible to change the linter that grunt.js uses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not out of the box, but you can create your own grunt task for JSLint using grunt's api: https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/api.md#creating-tasks

It's pretty simple, you can look through the tasks folder in grunt's source to see examples. https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/tree/master/tasks

If there isn't already an npm module for JSLint making one also isn't too difficult. Just add a package.json file to describe the JSLint node module you make and publish it, I can only post two links at a time but you can read the publish link at the npm home page.

You can also look through JSLint's config options and make JSHint's options the same. There should be options for most thing, and JSHint has even more options that JSLint does not have. The general usage is the same, mark up your code with comments, and run it. :)

Comment: Nice answer @s9tpepper

Answer (score 23):

**shameless self promotion**

There's a plugin for this: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-jslint

Comment: Thanks. I prefer JSLint because JSHint supporters seem to be trolls directing unwarranted hatred towards Douglas Crackford.